# I was asked to write scripts for a WordPress site. Can I just write the code in HTML & Javascript and ask him to paste it somewhere?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I was asked to write a cost estimator for someone's website. He told me it should be something like this: https://triplestamppress.com/pricing/

But I don't know much about WordPress yet.
I'm pretty confident in building this with HTML & Javascript, but I don't know how it should get imported to his WordPress site.

Is it as simple as writing the HTML code with a `<script>` tags and then asking him to paste it somewhere in his WordPress editor? If yes: Where should I tell him to paste it? If no: What should I lookup? Do I need to learn a bit of PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is similar and you can use **script** in your HTML pages.

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 

    // Some JavaScript code

    </script>
```

1. You can check https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-easily-add-javascript-in-wordpress-pages-or-posts/ for more info about JS in Wordpress
2. After you understand how simple it is you can paste in yourself. I recommend to start your own WordPress local project.

Answer (score 0):

If you write the code needed in  tags and ask him to paste this into the page needed, then as long as the code works it would be fine. There's no real need for PHP unless you're editing the header/footer files for the theme.

Also in case you're using a jquery library, you would need to include the cdn link as well, so you're code would look like:

HTML:

```
<div>Code Here</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>CDN</script>
<script>
 your code here
</script>
```

That should work fine.